# Microsoft Graph Api / OneDrive - Add/Remove photo tags

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is it possible to use the Microsoft Graph API to create/read/delete tags for photos stored in OneDrive?

I found an old [UserVoice request](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/7866669-include-tags-in-api) from 2015 but no recent news.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently no, this is not supported by the current API. As noted in the UserVoice you referenced, it is on the roadmap. However, I do not have an ETA for when this might show up.

I would suggest casing your votes and adding any additional comments to the existing request. This will help the OneDrive team with prioritizing this feature in their planning.